# Foreign Key error: MySQL ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, mariadb, mysql-error-1005

I have a problem in which I get the error message:

```
MySQL ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table
```

whenever I try to create a foreign key to link my two tables. I have tried a variety of different ways of phrasing the code but none seem to fix the error, the current code I am assuming is the closest to working:

```
ALTER TABLE requests
    ADD FOREIGN KEY FK_UserRequest(device_id) REFERENCES users(device_id)
```

I read through the other many posts regarding this topic but didn't seem to find a concise answer as to why this doesn't work. I'm hoping someone can specifically answer these questions:

- Does the foreign key need to reference a primary key? I've seen posts that say both yes and no to this question.
- Why does this specific code not work?

background info-

- engine is confirmed to be innoDB
- device_id is a column in both tables with the same attributes: CHAR(40)
- device_id in the users table is not a primary key
- database specifics: version 5.5.56-MariaDB

Comment: If napolis answer does not resolve your problem add table definitions to the question as text.

Comment: Please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to ensure your referenced key is an index of some sort.

Taken from: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys  [...]
>
> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any column or group of
> columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
> where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
> same order.